# Using evaluation functions with parameter in XGBoost (f_beta)

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm working on a classification problem where I have an unbalanced dataset and I am interested in having high precision.

Therefore, I would like to change the objective function for XGBoost to something that allows me to put more weight on precision. [F_beta score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html) seems to be doing just that, but I have a problem with it:

```
model_xgbm = XGBClassifier(objective=fbeta_score)
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_xgbm, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=n_iter_search,
                               scoring='average_precision')
```

This works, but I didn't supply a beta (I'm not even sure how does it work since beta is n obligatory parameter...)

```
model_xgbm = XGBClassifier(objective=fbeta_score(beta=0.5))
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_xgbm, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search,
                                   scoring='average_precision')
```

This simply doesn't work ("TypeError: fbeta_score() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)"). However, I can't really supply it with the other 2 arguments  here.

Is there a solution without copying or wrapping the function and pasting as a custom objective?

**EDIT :**
I found a function that might be useful: [make_param](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), but unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work:

```
model_xgbm = XGBClassifier(objective=make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=0.5))
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_xgbm, param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search,
                                   scoring='precision')
```

But this does not work either: "TypeError: __call__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)"
Note that I don't want to use it for model selection: I want it to be the objective function of my XGBoost estimator! Thus, the example at the bottom of the aforementioned link does not work for me.

**EDIT2 :** OK, so in fact the problem seems to be that XGBoost Classifier expects me to provide as the objective a function that returns a gradient and a hessian... does anyone know a wrapper that would do that for me?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the source code for passing in objective functions - it seems your code is complaining that it needs the `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments but since xgboost is just wrapped in ak learn I am not sure how it handles these lambda function.. I am actually interested in doing the same as I have a huge class imbalance I can come back once I have figured it out (or comeback if I haven't and someone else has!)

Comment: Nice to know someone is tackling a similar problem! Having read some more on the topic I now realize that the problem is that the objective function is a little bit low-level than I expected - it actually requires you to compute your own gradient and hessian.

Comment: I posted an answer - but mainly for future reference for wrappers for xgboost. It does not answer your ultimate problem but I will continue digging into it.

Comment: Well the real problem is that you are looking at the eval metric which is not the same as objective!

Eval metric lets you choose the models AFTER fitting them, while the objective function is used DURING fitting. For the purpose of eval_metric you can just use the sklearn.metrics function make_scorer :)

Comment: Actually it was a mistake on my part - I was passing the function as an objective ;)! I will update my post!

Comment: Yeah, now it looks good, I'm accepting as it explains what's the problem. Now I have to wonder - do people calculate their own hessians? Is there something like that out there on the internet? I don't really fancy doing all the math and implementing it in python myself...
Perhaps instead of that everybody just uses oversampling.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this part of the comments

```
eval_metric : str, callable, optional
        If a str, should be a built-in evaluation metric to use. See
        doc/parameter.md. If callable, a custom evaluation metric. The call
        signature is func(y_predicted, y_true) where y_true will be a
        DMatrix object such that you may need to call the get_label
        method. It must return a str, value pair where the str is a name
        for the evaluation and value is the value of the evaluation
        function. This objective is always minimized.
```

This is actually wrong as you require

```
func(y_true, y_predicted)
```

for passing a objective function.

It seems that if you wrap your `f_beta_score` as follows

```
def f_beta_wrapper(y_true, y_pred):
    beta = 0.5
    # note need to call .get_label() on y_true if using DMAtrix
    return fbeta_score(y_pred, y_true, beta)
```

and pass that in.

It flows through correctly bu it reaches the issue that you mentioned which is `fbeta_score` returns a `float` and not the two outputs it is expecting for which you can compute gradients from. More specifically

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.pyc in update(self, dtrain, iteration, fobj)
>
> 807         else:
>
> 808             pred = self.predict(dtrain)
>
> 809             grad, hess = fobj(pred, dtrain) # error here
>
> 810             self.boost(dtrain, grad, hess)
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

This makes sense as the `objective` function is being minimized so we require outputs that are akin to minimizing parameters i.e. gradients.